# How to make a copy of shared read-only Word doc in OneDrive

Tags: office-365, onedrive, online-storage

TLDR; make a copy of shared read-only Word doc in onedrive.

I've shared a file with my students using an "anyone with the link can view" url.

I need the students to be able to make their own copy of the file on their own OneDrive. But they can't directly make a copy using a "view only" link

If the file as shared as "editable" and the file is opened by a student, there will be a "Save as" option in the File menu. But in "View only" mode the "save as"  (and all the menus) are unavailable.

I could have the students "download" my file and then upload a copy to their OneDrive, but that seems clunky and I am trying to simplify things.

Also, they won't have OneDrive client installed.